# read/write xlsx in kotlin/js

Tags: javascript, kotlin, xlsx

I am working in `Kotlin/js (react)`, and I want to read/write xlsx file when select file in **html input tag**

I already know I need to use `Apache Poi library` to do that in `Kotlin` or `Java`, but as I know, in kotlin/js, we can't import java library

So how can I do that without  using `Apache Poi`/`Java library`?

Thank you so much